# PHP MYSQL query a join table for to get last row for parent table query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, group-by

I have two tables : ticket & history_ticket

Table ticket :

```
ticket_id  | ticket_desc   
 1         |  software   
 2         |  hardware   
 3         |  other
```

Table history_ticket :

```
history_id | ticket_id | message  | status    
 1         |  1        |  text    |  process 
 2         |  2        |  text    |  solve   
 3         |  3        |  text    |  process
 4         |  3        |  text    |  solve
```

I want result like this

```
ticket_id  | ticket_desc  | status 
 1         |  software    |  process
 2         |  hardware    |  solve
 3         |  other       |  solve
```

I've tried various joins and subselects, but no luck

Any help/directions will be much appreciated!

UPDATE : How if i change the result, like this

```
ticket_id  | ticket_desc  | last_status | count_message
     1     |  software    |  process    |     1
     2     |  hardware    |  solve      |     1
     3     |  other       |  solve      |     2
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql: Using LIMIT within GROUP BY to get N results per group?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129693/mysql-using-limit-within-group-by-to-get-n-results-per-group)

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  t.ticket_id, 
  ticket_desc, 
  ht.status
FROM ticket AS t
INNER JOIN history_ticket AS ht ON t.ticket_id = ht.ticket_id
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT ticket_id, MAX(history_id) maxid
   FROM history_ticket
   GROUP BY ticket_id
) AS ht2 ON ht.history_id = ht2.maxid;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0d086/3)

This will give you:

```
| TICKET_ID | TICKET_DESC |  STATUS |
-------------------------------------
|         1 |    software | process |
|         2 |    hardware |   solve |
|         3 |     Problem |   solve |
```

---

### UPDATE 1

To get the count of messages for each ticket, you can simply include `COUNT(history_id) AS sum_message` in the subquery like this:

```
SELECT
  t.ticket_id, 
  ticket_desc, 
  ht.status, 
  ht2.sum_message
FROM ticket AS t
INNER JOIN history_ticket ht ON t.ticket_id = ht.ticket_id
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT 
     ticket_id, 
     MAX(history_id) maxid, 
     COUNT(history_id) AS sum_message
   FROM history_ticket
   GROUP BY ticket_id
) AS ht2 ON ht.history_id = ht2.maxid;
```

### [Updated SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0d086/5)

This will give you:

```
| TICKET_ID | TICKET_DESC |  STATUS | SUM_MESSAGE |
---------------------------------------------------
|         1 |    software | process |           1 |
|         2 |    hardware |   solve |           1 |
|         3 |     Problem |   solve |           2 |
```

---

### Update 2

If you want to select names for the ids `divisi_id`, for simple values, you can use the `CASE` expression for this:

```
SELECT
  t.ticket_id, 
  ticket_desc, 
  CASE 
    WHEN t.divisi_id = 101 THEN 'Divisi A'
    WHEN t.divisi_id = 102 THEN 'Divisi B'
  END AS 'Divisi',
  ht.status, 
  ht2.sum_message
FROM ticket AS t
INNER JOIN history_ticket ht ON t.ticket_id = ht.hticket_id
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT hticket_id, MAX(history_id) maxid, COUNT(history_id) AS sum_message
   FROM history_ticket
   GROUP BY hticket_id
) AS ht2 ON ht.history_id = ht2.maxid;
```

### [Updated SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eba04/6)

This will give you:

```
| TICKET_ID | TICKET_DESC |   DIVISI |  STATUS | SUM_MESSAGE |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|         1 |    software | Divisi A | process |           1 |
|         2 |    hardware | Divisi B |   solve |           1 |
|         3 |     Problem | Divisi A |   solve |           2 |
```

For multiple values, you can put them in a temp table, or you can select them in a subquery and join the table to get the name like this:

```
SELECT
  t.ticket_id, 
  ticket_desc, 
  d.Divisi,
  ht.status, 
  ht2.sum_message
FROM ticket AS t
INNER JOIN history_ticket ht ON t.ticket_id = ht.hticket_id
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT hticket_id, MAX(history_id) maxid, COUNT(history_id) AS sum_message
   FROM history_ticket
   GROUP BY hticket_id
) AS ht2 ON ht.history_id = ht2.maxid
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT 101 AS divisi_id, 'Divisi A' AS Divisi
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 102             , 'Divisi B'
  ... -- here you put other values or you can join a temp table instead
) AS D ON t.divisi_id = D.divisi_id;
```

### [Updated SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eba04/7)

Comment: Sorry i'm newbie for mysql query. But i try to implemented your scheme on my database. And i still confuse :( I update the question, please help. Thank you.

Comment: @Hafiz - Why are you confused? Have you tried it? If it doesn't work can you please post the errors you got if any? or you can try to edit [the demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0d086/3) example to explain the issue.

Comment: @Hafiz OK, See my edit, I think it is count of messages not the sum.

Comment: What if in [the demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e79ae/1), i change ticket_id into hticket_id at history_ticket

Comment: @Hafiz Just change it in the `ON` clause, make it `ON t.ticket_id = ht.hticket_id` instead of `ON t.ticket_id = ht.ticket_id`. Like in [**this updated sql fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e79ae/5).

Comment: Dear @Mahmoud Gamal, can you help me again. I have another column name 'divisi_id' in table ticket. I want add into query results, but change the value example 101 => 'Divisi A' , 102 => 'Divisi B', etc. Thanks before. [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eba04/1)

Comment: @Hafiz - Its al right, feel free to ask again any time if anything goes wrong. OK, but where does these values `'Divisi A'`, `Divisi B`, ... etc come from? Are there are more values or just limited number? And is it ok to create a temp table for them?

Comment: Hmmm.... How to add other value?  [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c7290/2)

Comment: @Hafiz - Put `UNION ALL` for each select: [**Fixed SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c7290/3)

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct ticket.ticket_id, ticket.ticket_desc, history_ticket.status 
from ticket 
join history_ticket on ticket_id
```

This, as far as I remember, will choose a description and status at random if you have more than one. If you want to apply a specific rule to which one to pick, give more info and we can help you on that.

Comment: how does this solve the OP's problem? that's just a straight join. he wants only one row per record group.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    tk.ticket_id, 
    tk.ticket_desc, 
    ht.status 
FROM ticket tk JOIN history_ticket ht ON tk.ticket_id = tk.ticket_id 
ORDER BY tk.ticket_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
Select distinct t.ticket_id, t.ticket_desc, h.status 
from ticket t, history_ticket h
where t.ticket_id = h.ticket_id
order by t.ticket_id
```